# A glass of water on an inclined plane

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, acceleration

A Glass of water is freely sliding down an inclined plane. The water surface has settled down after some initial disturbances. Which of the three cases is possible for the shape of the water surface:

1. It will remain parallel to the incline
2. The water surface will rise towards the direction of the acceleration parallel to incline
3. The water surface will rise away from the direction of acceleration parallel to incline.

In the following [forum](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/a-glass-of-water-on-an-inclined-plane.414467/) it says answer is 1, how does it happen?

Comment: Instead of a glass of water, imagine you have a block sliding down a smooth plane with a sphere on top of the block (assume no friction between block and plane or between block and sphere). In equilibrium, will the sphere move relative to the block ?

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics SE. Please, do not post pictures. Type the question instead (and using MathJax for formulae).  There are many reasons, including facilitation for algorithms and helping users whose device doesn't display them well.  Use a more formal language as well. Thank you.

Comment: changed the question accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is 1, as you have found - the water surface remains parallel to the incline. As to how to get the answer without writing all the equations, draw a diagram showing the acceleration vectors.

There will be gravitational acceleration (vertically down), acceleration parallel to the surface of the inclined plane $g \sin \theta$, and the normal force to the surface of the inclined plane $g \cos \theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle the plane makes with the horizontal.

As the glass of water is *freely sliding* down the inclined plane there is no friction, so the *reaction force consists of only the normal force*. The surface of the water will be perpendicular to the reaction force, thus *parallel to the surface of the inclined plane*.

Consider, if the glass is sitting at rest on a flat surface, the reaction force consists of only the normal force, and surface of the water will be perpendicular to the reaction force, thus parallel to the flat surface.

If the glass is not freely sliding, i.e. friction is involved, then the reaction force would consist of both the normal force and the friction force, and the resultant vector would somewhere between the normal to the inclined plane and vertical, and the surface of the water would be at a corresponding angle between the angle of the inclined plane and horizontal.

Three diagrams, one for each case (freely sliding, flat surface, and sliding with friction), without needing to include calculations, would show that the answer is that the water surface remains parallel to the incline.

Comment: **The surface of the water will be perpendicular to the reaction force** how can u say this? is there a theory or something?

Comment: Compare a container of water resting on a horizontal surface, and a container spun in a circle at the end of a tether (centripetal force involved). In both cases the water stays in the container...

Answer (score 0):

The only effect a plane would have on that glass of water would be if the plane would accelerate. Assuming that the plane travels at constant speed perfectly perpendicular to earth's centre, the water's surface will behave just the same as on ground.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be differing opinions in the thread you linked. It seems some of the opinions in that thread arose from users trying out the experiment with real glasses of water, and they arrived at conclusion other than 1. However, assuming by 'freely' you mean 'frictionlessly' I believe the correct answer is indeed 1 (in which case the tests construed in the other forum are different from the ideal model).

To see this, note that the force of gravity acts on the glass and the water inside but not on the plane. In a frame of reference that accelerates downwards at a rate of g, there is an effective upwards force on the plane of $g$, and no force on the water or glass except for the normal force of the plane and the hydrodynamic forces of the water and the glass. Thus, in this reference frame, we have the equivalent of a static force on the glass in the direction $R$ (this pseudo-force has magnitude $g \cos \theta$). Thus, if we focus on the frame of reference where the glass is not moving, there is a force on the water in the glass in the direction of $-R$, and the water should behave as it would in the case where the glass is sitting still on a flat surface perpendicular to a gravitational field. That is, the surface of the water should end up parallel to the bottom of the glass.